# Ionic cannot find name 'AES256' while importing AES256

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, encryption

Referring to Ionic documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/aes-256/

I added AES-256 encryption package by:

```
import { AES256 } from '@ionic-native/aes-256';
```

But I'm getting this error:

**typescript: Cannot find name 'AES256'**

While I'm trying to define the corresponding variable in the constructor:

```
private aes256: AES256
```

Ionic version: 4.8.0

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by looking to the same problem for other libraries.
The solution to the problem is adding 'ngx' to the import:

```
import { AES256 } from '@ionic-native/aes-256/ngx';
```

Comment: But ngx is not available in aes-256 package

Comment: you have to download the latest package